# Difference Between Codeigniter 3.x and Codeigniter 2.x

Tags: php, codeigniter

- I want to know that there is there new functions in Codeigniter 3.x not present in Codeigniter 2.x
- Major Changes
- Is there any function which is worked in CI 2.x and not in 3.x

Because i want to made my site 2.2.0 to 3.0.6

Thanks in advance
:)

Comment: read docs https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/installation/upgrade_300.html

Comment: or changelog https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/changelog.html

Answer (score 2):

One of the main changes are that. The first letter only must be upper case on file names and class names.

For Example

Filename: **Example.php**

```
<?php

class Example extends CI_Controller {

public function index() {

}

}
```

Model

Filename: **Model_example.php**

```
<?php

class Model_example extends CI_Model {

public function some_fun_name() {

}

}
```

Comment: and what about xss_clean for form validation